# Numpy array comas | Python

Tags: python, numpy

Cuando un imprimo un numpy array simple lo imprimo sin comas pero cuando lo adjunto a una lista e imprimo la lista este aparece con coma. Cambia en algo su comportamiento?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
list1 = [[1.23, 2.56, 3.12]]
array = np.array(list1)

print(array)
print(" ")

list2 = []
list2.append(array)

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primer caso**

En el primer caso haces

```
print(array)
```

y obtienes

```
[[1.23 2.56 3.12]]
```

estas invocando a `_array_str_implementation`, quien llama a `array2string` para generar la lista de valores separados por blancos, como lo señala el quinto parámetro de la llamada.

```
return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "")
```

---

**Segundo caso**

Cuando ejecutas

```
print(list2)
```

y obtienes

```
[array([[1.23, 2.56, 3.12]])]
```

estas invocando a `_array_repr_implementation`, que efectivamente distingue arreglos `numpy` de otros arreglos. Mirando en su implementación, vemos:

```
if type(arr) is not ndarray:
    class_name = type(arr).__name__
else:
    class_name = "array"

skipdtype = dtype_is_implied(arr.dtype) and arr.size > 0

prefix = class_name + "("
suffix = ")" if skipdtype else ","
```

En este segmento del código, la variable `skipdtype` es `True` cuando se trata de arreglos numpy, por lo que

- `prefix` es `"array("`
- `suffix` queda como `")"` en lugar de `","`

La lista misma se genera con un llamado a `array2string`, igual que en el caso anterior, pero pasando en el quinto parámetro `", "` como separador:

```
lst = array2string(arr, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ', ', prefix, suffix=suffix)
```

Eso justifica la diferencia, aunque no el motivo.